# Yaml typecast variables in arithmetic operations

Tags: python, yaml, config, pyyaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
somthing:
  a: &a_num 5 
  b: &b_num 32
  c: !!python/object/apply:eval [ 5 * 32] # works
  d: !!python/object/apply:eval [ *a_num * *a_num] # throws error
```

Error:

> expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found ' '

What I tried to typecast the variables fo floats:

`c: !!python/object/apply:eval [ !!float *a * !!float *b]`

but that also did not work

How can I do arithmetic operations on variables?

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to work without making a modified loader, an alternative `eval` and/or rewriting your YAML.

If you'd try to load then dump this:

```
  c: [ 5 * 32]
```

you'd see that that unquoted scalar is equivalent to:

```
  c: ['5 * 32']
```

so your call to eval get, as argument a list with a single string.

Your YAML needs to be valid, and your's isn't, so your program never gets to call eval for the second time around. The parsing of `[ *a_num * *a_num]` does fail because the `*` at the beginning of this node does preclude an unquoted scalar from being parsed as this is recognised as an alias instead. The alias is parsed (until the space after `a_num`) and then the parser expects a comma for the next list element or a closing `]`. It tries to parse an alias again, and if it could, it would still complain about the comma (try using `[ *a_num  *a_num]` to see that effect, you'll never reach the `eval` call).

So you would either have to resort to your own eval alternative that knows how to handle a sequence of elements ( `[*a_num, '*', *a_num]` ) as argument (as this has to be valid YAML), or alternatively you have such an alternative access the anchor/alias mechanism and present it with `[ '*a_num * *a_num' ]`.

Comment: `[ '*a_num * *a_num' ]` throws a syntax error. When trying to do (*a_num) it also gives a syntax error.

Comment: So basically there is no easy way to simply add two variables in yaml?

Comment: No there is not, as there are no variables in YAML (only anchors and aliases), nor is there any arithmatic. Python's eval can only handle strings, so you really need to make a class that handles the terms of the addition, and you have to follow YAML syntax. Maybe you should look at a templating language like jinja2 and run that before loading the YAML.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other "config file" kind of type that is similar to the yaml hierarchy but supports variables out of the box without the need for a templating language like jinja?

Comment: Not that I know. I have made [PON](https://pypi.org/project/pon/) which has the arithmetic built in, but doesn't have anchors+aliases or variables. Using the syntax `d: !eval [ $a_num * $a_num]` and ruamel.yaml in default (round-trip-mode) you need only two small recursive routines to 1) find the anchors and their values, 2) eval tagged nodes (there is no need to make a handler for !eval), but in PyYAML although you can preserve the anchors, they will be associated with not-yet-constructed node elements.